# Python app for SolidWorks connecting to COM object (pythoncom.connnect()) returns an error/malformed object

Tags: python, com, solidworks

I'm working on python app for Solidworks.
There no straight API for python, but it has COM object that can be used for it.
I searched for COM usage in python and found couple options:
pythoncom, win32com, comtypes (as I get, they has the same roots).

As an example using it with Excel all working well.
But with solidworks for some reason I have a problem.
First:

```
import win32com
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

this is working well. can do everything with that object.

but using it with solidworks

```
import win32com
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Sldworks.Application.29")
```

its making an object,  but it's not accessible

```
dir(app)
```

returns an error:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147319765, 'Element not found.', None, None)
....

```
app.__dict__()
```

returns:

{'*oleobj*': <PyIDispatch at 0x0000012B81238AD0 with obj at 0x0000012BFBE0D238>, '*username*': 'Sldworks.Application', '*olerepr*': <win32com.client.build.DispatchItem object at 0x0000012BFE490580>, '*mapCachedItems*': {}, '*builtMethods*': {}, '*enum*': None, '*unicode_to_string*': None, '*lazydata*': None}

But the object is accessible.

Trying:

```
import pythoncom
app = pythoncom.connect("Sldworks.Application.29")
```

returns an error
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)

Same for

```
app = win32.GetActiveObject("Sldworks.Application.29")
```

But the weirdest thing is that I can manipulate with the object (have the list of methods), but looks like the object is malformed.

On the other side, this one looks working, but loads very very slow: (update: its loading slow first time. Then ok)

```
import comtypes.client as CC
app = CC.CreateObject("Sldworks.Application.29")
```

What's wrong with Solidwroks, why I cannot connect to opened app with winn32com.client.Dispatch()/pythoncom.connect("Sldworks.Application.29") and get all methods and properties from app object?

Solidworks 2019/21 64bit, Python 3.8.8 64 and 32 bit (both have the same result)
Thanks

Update:
Loading issue I resolved with two steps:
first load COM object with win32com Dispatch(), then using comtypes.CreateObject(). But its way to complicated.
Looking for better solution.

Comment: Can't test because I don't have solidworks, but from a python+COM point of view this is the good way: `import win32com.client app = win32com.client.Dispatch("SldWorks.Application")` equivalent to this VB https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS_Visible_or_BackGround_Example_VB.htm . 29 is for the version but it depends on your setup, you shouldn' use it directly, using SldWorks.Application should be enough. Check your the registry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Comment: you  partly right.
I have two SW ver installed, so  I should use version. 
My main question whats wrong with the COM object itself?! I cannot access it normally like Excel. with ```win32com.client.Dispatch("")```
Can I dump the object somehow to show it?
Thanks

Comment: another wired thing:
calling on such object (win32com) invokes the method, but  returns an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\URS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 226, in __call__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs), self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName, None
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem, I can use win32com.client.Dispatch () to open SW, can also use swApp.OpenDoc () to open a SW file, but I want to continue to use GetActiveConfiguration (), it will prompt the same as you error, I don't know what happened, I checked my API and pywin32, but I don't know where the problem is

Comment: Hey, after a million tries I have found a proper way to communicate with sw as a com object. Using clr. Took me a while but i managed. But i moved to c# anyway, coz I had to make a binary app that could not be decompiled to code since im making a paid app )